# Merge dataframes on timestamps and time intervals using data.table in R

Tags: datetime, r

I have two `dataframes` (`x` and `y`) that I need to join, conditional on the timestamp in `x` falling within the time interval of two columns in `y`.  I've accomplished this using `data.table::foverlaps()` by adapting some of the code in [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694729/r-merge-2-dataframes-with-timestamp-between)), but in order to get it to work on my data I had to set the `key` of `data.table` `x`, which according to the documentation of `foverlaps()`, isn't supposed to be necessary.

Am I using this `foverlaps()`incorrectly? If so, new ideas for how to accomplish this data merging task are welcome.

```
library(data.table)
```

### Data snippets

```
x <- structure(list(TagID = c(20161L, 23055L, 45428L, 2627L), DateTimePST = structure(c(1415481096, 
1380768444, 1474560076, 1511384035), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "Pacific/Pitcairn"), Receiver = c(102140L, 112568L, 
112568L, 121907L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

y <- structure(list(Station = c("YBAAG4", "YBAAG4", "YBCSSW", "YBCSSW", 
"YBBCD", "YBAWW"), Receiver = c(102140L, 102140L, 112568L, 112568L, 
121907L, 121907L), Start = structure(c(1464979020, 1409256300, 
1369945920, 1470761034, 1505494980, 1409246700), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Pacific/Pitcairn"), End = structure(c(1473357300, 
1421878500, 1382638020, 1479838293, 1513282440, 1421871360), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "Pacific/Pitcairn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

# preview data
> x
  TagID         DateTimePST Receiver
1 20161 2014-11-08 13:11:36   102140
2 23055 2013-10-02 18:47:24   112568
3 45428 2016-09-22 08:01:16   112568
4  2627 2017-11-22 12:53:55   121907

> y
  Station Receiver               Start                 End
1  YBAAG4   102140 2016-06-03 10:37:00 2016-09-08 09:55:00
2  YBAAG4   102140 2014-08-28 12:05:00 2015-01-21 14:15:00
3  YBCSSW   112568 2013-05-30 12:32:00 2013-10-24 10:07:00
4  YBCSSW   112568 2016-08-09 08:43:54 2016-11-22 10:11:33
5   YBBCD   121907 2017-09-15 09:03:00 2017-12-14 12:14:00
6   YBAWW   121907 2014-08-28 09:25:00 2015-01-21 12:16:00
```

Because some `Receiver` numbers are associated with more than one `Station`, it is important to merge these two datasets on the timestamp (`DateTimePST`), not on the receiver number.

### Prep data

```
x <- as.data.table(x); x$Start = x$DateTimePST; x$End = x$DateTimePST # needs these start and end columns, otherwise foverlaps throws an error
y <- as.data.table(y)
# set keys: if I omit setting the key on x, forverlap() throws an error
setkey(y, Start, End); setkey(x, Start, End)
```

### `foverlaps()` join, then discard incorrect `Receiver` pairs

```
result <- data.frame(foverlaps(x, y, type = "within"))
result <- result[result$Receiver == result$i.Receiver, ] # this filters down to the correct receiver matches
```

### Clean up results

```
rm_col <- c("i.Receiver", "i.Start", "i.End")
result <- result[ , !(colnames(result) %in% rm_col)]
result

Station Receiver               Start                 End TagID         DateTimePST
1  YBCSSW   112568 2013-05-30 12:32:00 2013-10-24 10:07:00 23055 2013-10-02 18:47:24
3  YBAAG4   102140 2014-08-28 12:05:00 2015-01-21 14:15:00 20161 2014-11-08 13:11:36
4  YBCSSW   112568 2016-08-09 08:43:54 2016-11-22 10:11:33 45428 2016-09-22 08:01:16
5   YBBCD   121907 2017-09-15 09:03:00 2017-12-14 12:14:00  2627 2017-11-22 12:53:55
```

### Wrap in a function:

```
getStation <- function(x, y) {
  x <- as.data.table(x); x$Start = x$DateTimePST; x$End = x$DateTimePST
  y <- as.data.table(y)
  setkey(y, Start, End); setkey(x, Start, End)
  result <- data.frame(foverlaps(x, y, type = "within"))
  result <- result[result$Receiver == result$i.Receiver, ]
  result <- result[ , !(colnames(result) %in% c("i.Receiver", "i.Start", "i.End"))]
}

res <- getStation(x, y)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use `by.x` to get around setting `x`'s key.

Also, note that `foverlaps` can merge on any number of keys, and then do the overlaps *only on the final two*. What that means here is that you can do the `x.Receiver == i.Receiver` filter up-front, which also simplifies the clean-up step.

```
x = as.data.table(x)
x[ , end := DateTimePST]
y = as.data.table(y)

setkey(y, Receiver, Start, End)

result = foverlaps(x, y, by.x = c('Receiver', 'DateTimePST', 'end'), type = 'within')
result[ , end := NULL]

setDF(result)
```

I do find it a bit awkward/strange that you've got to define `end` when `by.x = c('Receiver', 'DateTimePST', 'DateTimePST')` would appear to be fine, and have filed [a feature request](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3721).

If you don't need `DateTimePST` in your output, you might find the non-equi-join version more compact / easier to read:

```
y[x, on = .(Receiver == Receiver, Start < DateTimePST, End > DateTimePST)]
#    Station Receiver               Start                 End
# 1:  YBAAG4   102140 2014-11-08 13:11:36 2014-11-08 13:11:36
# 2:  YBCSSW   112568 2013-10-02 18:47:24 2013-10-02 18:47:24
# 3:  YBCSSW   112568 2016-09-22 08:01:16 2016-09-22 08:01:16
# 4:   YBBCD   121907 2017-11-22 12:53:55 2017-11-22 12:53:55
#    TagID
# 1: 20161
# 2: 23055
# 3: 45428
# 4:  2627
```

Note the order `y[x` -- we're using `x` to "look up" rows of `y`.

If you *do* need `DateTimePST`, it's just a bit of an ugly extension:

```
y[x, c(.SD, list(DateTimePST=DateTimePST)),
  on = .(Receiver == Receiver, Start < DateTimePST, End > DateTimePST)]
```

Finally, we can think of this as adding columns to `x` by a non-equi-join with `y` by reversing the order:

```
x[y, `:=`(Start = i.Start, End = i.End, Station = i.Station),
  on = .(Receiver == Receiver, DateTimePST > Start, DateTimePST < End)]
```

Comment: Super helpful options, thank you!  I do need `DateTimePST`, so the last two methods were both good ones.  One note on the "ugly extension" one, that only works for me when I set `x$Start = x$DateTimePST`, otherwise I get an error: "`Error in `[.data.table`(y, x, c(.SD, list(DateTimePST = DateTimePST)),  : 
  column(s) not found: Start`" .  I'm still learning `data.table` though